# Estimation of Bayes Error / Human-level error

Tags: bayes-error

In one of course Andrew Ng mentioned that model (Machine learning) error can't outperform Bayes / human level performance and hence the bias can't avoided.. (Unavoidable bias)

How do we determine / estimate Bayes error or human level error so that we could stop optimizing the model for reducing bias further?

Examples / concepts for classification problem would be appreciated...

Comment: Hi, have you ever managed to figure this out? I am asking myself the same question but can't find an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Bayes error and human error are two different concepts. Bayes error is the theoretical lowest error possible on a task, there can be no lower error rate. Human error is the empirical lowest error that a human can perform.

Since Bayes error is theoretical, for most non-trivial tasks Bayes error must be estimated based on domain knowledge.

Human error can be found by having human perform the task.

A popular example is ImageNet. Current machine learning systems are better than humans error (top-5 error rate of ~4-5%) and rapidly approach Bayes error rate (top-5 error rate of <3%).